# Grep all at once

Tags: grep, performance

The script I have receives arguments and needs to grep through another file. Script loops through every argument.

Is there a way to collect the arguments in a single search string and grep with OR ? I'd like to do this to improve the speed hoping that searching everything at once will make my script faster. Appreciate any ideas.

Comment: I'm sorry, i just love the title to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`egrep` (or `grep -E`) can do OR:

```
egrep "string|string|string" <file>
```

Comment: yes, does this goes over the file once or thrice ?

Comment: One time.  This solution uses extended regex feature of modern `grep` binaries.  Historically `egrep` and `grep` were separate binaries.

Comment: I'm having an issue with getting a string of all the arguments. How would I print out all the arguments with "|" in between ?

Comment: `echo "string string string" | tr " " "|"`

Answer (score 5):

```
grep -e foo -e bar -e baz files
```

or:

```
grep 'foo
bar
baz' files
```

If those `foo`, `bar`, `baz` are meant to be strings as opposed to basic regular expressions, add the `-F` option to those 2 `grep`  commands above.

For extended regular expressions:

```
grep -E 'foo|bar|baz' files
```

If the list of strings is in the positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`...):

```
NL='
'
IFS=$NL  # or IFS=$'\n' with ksh93/zsh/bash/mksh/FreeBSD sh...
grep -Fe "$*" files
```

(`$*` is the concatenation of the positional parameters with the first character of `$IFS`)

Comment: I guess we both saw the same thing. I just deleted mine, but could you mention `grep ''` or `-E '||'`, or `grep "$NL"` please?

Comment: @mikeserv, the empty string is found in every string, that's why including the empty string in the list of searches will match every line. Not sure it's worth mentioning here.

Comment: Well, yeah, I get that, and you have a point. The only reason I considered it worth doing so was that elsewhere `echo "string string string" | tr " " "|"` is recommended, which would be problematic given an argument like `fn '  *'` - if you take my meaning - *(even if that would be a syntax error as written for Eregexp)*.

Comment: keep it simple, `grep -E 'foo|ba[rz]' files`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be using [ack](http://www.betterthangrep.com) which supports extended regex by default:

`ack "one|two"`

For case insensitivity use `ack -i` and for non-standard filetypes use `ack --all`.